# Query that will delete records from table1 if reference is not found in table2

Tags: mysql

```
table1
refno status
1     A
2     A
6     A
3     A

table2
refno itemcode qty
1     1        5
1     2        0
3     8        0
3     1        0
2     4        3
6     7        0
```

I need a query that will delete all rows in [table2] that qty=0 at the same time will delete rows in [table1] if the [refno] is not found in [table2]

Given the above example, the query should retain the following output:

```
table1
refno status
1     A
2     A

table2
refno itemcode qty
1     1        5
2     4        3
```

Thanks

Comment: @MahmoudGamal - MySQL has a [Multiple-table delete syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html)

Answer (score 0):

The following query will `DELETE` all the records from the two tables:

```
DELETE t1.*, t2.*
FROM Table t1
LEFT JOIN
(
   SELECT *
   FROM Table2
   WHERE qty = 0
) t2 ON t1.refno = t2.refno 
WHERE t2.refno IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write 2 delete statements in a transaction to make sure its a atomic operation.

Answer (score 0):

with mysql, as multi-tables delete are allowed

```
delete  t1, t2 
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.refno = t2.refno
where t2.qty = 0 or t2.refno is null;
```

but this will delete line `1, A` from table1 (because we've got a relation in T2 where `refno = 1` and `qty = 0`)

And I don't see a solution (maybe one will) where line `1, 2, 0` from table2 will be delete and line `1, A` from table1 won't be.

So, I think the solution must be a stored procedure (or 2 queries)

```
create procedure CleanTable1Table2()
begin
  delete from table2 t2
  where qty = 0;

  delete from table1 t1
  where not exists (select null from table2 t2
                    where t2.refno= t1.refno);
end
```